# How to make a single excel sheet as readable and writable with JXL in java?

Tags: java, jxl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write to the SAME excel sheet using JXL API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311199/how-to-write-to-the-same-excel-sheet-using-jxl-api)

i am reading one excel file and validating the same. If validation is not success, i want to display some error on the same sheet. So how it can be possible? Can any one have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way is to create a temporary file of the original file and read the temporary file. Do the validations. Open the original file for writing and display the error message. Finally delete the temporary file :-)